# Creating multiple event listeners using a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

Trying to create multiple listeners with a loop. How to make it work?

```
var buttons = ['one', 'two', 'tree'];
$.each(keys, function(key, value) {
    $(value).click(function() {
        // do something
    });
});
```

Also, is there a shortcut to not writing `key, value` when I only need the value?

Comment: Place all your buttons in the DOM with common class and then simply attach the listener to that class as you are using jQuery

Comment: Unless your elements are XML-like `<one> <two>` etc... you're missing a key factor of assigning a *class* or *Id* like in: `['#one', '#two', '#three']`

Comment: Have you tried using a delegated event listener? If all the elements are  invoking the same callback on the same event, there is no need to place a separate listener on each element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are better off putting a delegated event listener on a parent instead of iterating through every button. For example, if you place all your `<button>` elements inside of a `<div>` with the id `#container`, then you can write your listener like this:

```
$('#container').on('click', 'button', function() {
  // do something;
});
```

Now, every time a button element is clicked within that div, your callback will be invoked. You can also use a class selector in place of `'button'` to only listen to elements that have that class.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make it work by looping then you can use

```
var buttons = ['.one', '.two', '.three'];

// ---------------- with -------- $.each();

$.each( buttons, function(key, value) {
    $(value).click(function() {
        // ------------- Do something
    });
});


// ------------------ with ----------- for loop


for( var i=0 ; i < buttons.length ; i++ )
{
    $(buttons[i]).click(function({
    // ------------- Do something
    });
}
```

**But why to go this round** if just want to assign event

```
$('.one, .two, .three, #one, #two, #three').click(function() {
     // ------------- Do something
});
```

**OR if having variable**

```
var buttons = '.one, .two, .three, #one, #two, #three';
$(buttons).click(function() {
     // ------------- Do something
});
```

AND THATS IT **no key, no value, no for, no each**

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you can select some elements together, and seperate them using colon **,**

```
var buttons = ['one', 'two', 'tree'];
$(buttons.join()).click(function(){
  // Do something
})
```

In this example I'm using join to convert the array to `one,two,three` then I add one event listener to all those element

Comment: Want this fire the event multiple times? Means if the array contains 3 values then the code inside the event listner will execute for three times.

Comment: It will fire want to for each click.

Comment: default for `join()` is a comma so don't even need the delimiter argument ... `buttons.join()` will do same

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you'd be better off assigning the click handler to a button with a specific class name instead of iterating over a list of selectors and assigning a new function inside a loop.

```
<button class='my-button' id="one">
  One
</button>
<button class='my-button' id="two">
  Two
</button>
<button class='my-button' id="three">
  Three
</button>
```

and the JS

```
$('.my-button').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('body').append("<div>Button " + id + " was clicked</div>");
});
```

Take a look this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4e7rk10L/

Answer (score -1):

If you really want loop (This was your question) you can do this:

```
for(var i=0;i<buttons.length;i++)
  $(buttons[i]).click(function({
    // Do something
  })
```

Comment: Don't create functions inside loops. It's bad design.

Comment: Also note that `function({` should be actually `function() {`

Comment: Sure. the I is defined out of scope. See how to solve it: https://jsbin.com/rumuzopobu/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Another way without `bind` : https://jsbin.com/xasiwayuba/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: I'd not write in any case code that might oddly result in unexpected behavior. The best way is following some clean code mindset. `.join()` (without the unneeded `","` to the rescue - as in your first answer) since the `$(selectors)` will already be an jQ wrapper to an iterable **collection** of Elements.